# Replace previous array of object is adding new element every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react js` and `Redux`. Here ,  I have an array of object which is like ,

```
const initialState = {
    Low: [
        {
            id: 0,
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 6,
            level: 'EASY'
        }
    ],
    Medium: [
        {
            id: 0,
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'MEDIUM'
        }
    ],
    High: [
        {
            id: 0,
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'TOUGH'
        }
    ]
}
```

this is in the reducer .

Now,I do have an onChange function which actually changes the values in this array.

```
onChange(event, tobeupdated, id, type, noc, data) {
   let newData = { ...this.props.data };
    if (newData) {
      let data = newData[type].map((object, index) => {
        if (object.id === id) {
          object[tobeupdated] = event.target.value;
          const tobeData = newData[type];
         this.props.updateLowLevel({tobeData, type}).then(() => {
            let criteria_filled = this.disableAddbutton({ ...this.props.data }, type);
            addedRow = `new${type}RowAdded`;
            this.setState({
              [addedRow]: criteria_filled ? true : false
            })
});
}
```

From this, I am updating the value of that object. Depends upon the type .

Now, In action creator,

```
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: QUIZ_DATA,
      data: tobeUpdated,
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

In my reducer, I am updating it like,

```
 case QUIZ_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.data.type]: [action.data.tobeData],
                error: false,
            }
```

Now, Here what is happening when I change the let's say `type` then it adds that array of object to that, but when I try to change the diff key  that time what it does is,

In the array of object, one more obj gets added in the element. SO, because of that, I am not able to get that render properly.

Can anyone help me with this?